# ASP.Net MVC 4/5 - Refresh routing at runtime

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

In an MVC-based content management system, the users can create new pages at runtime and specify a slug for the page.

I register these slugs/routes at application_startup, and it works great:

```
foreach (var slug in pagesSlugs)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: $"Page-{slug}",
                url: $"{slug}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Details", slug = slug }
            );
        }
```

How can I re-run RegisterRoutes at runtime, when a user has created a new page?

**Note:**

Since the user can create ANY slug, I cannot create a dynamic route with a pattern, like /pages/{slug}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to add new routes at run-time, and in fact you should only have one route for your 'slug', but add a route constraint that looks up a table of your user's slugs. If it matches a value in the database, then it will execute that route, otherwise it will fall to the next matching route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Page",
    url: "{slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Details" }
    constraints: new { slug = new SlugConstraint() }
)

public class SlugConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> slugs = ... // your code to get the slugs
        // Get the slug from the url
        var slug  = values["slug"].ToString().ToLower();
        // Check for a match (assumes case insensitive)
        return slugs.Any(x => x.ToLower() == slug);
    }
}
```

Since this will be called in each request, you should consider caching the slugs (say in `MemoryCache`) and each time a new page is created by a user, invalidate the cache and refresh it again from the database.

Comment: Excellent, that makes things a lot easier to manage than generating the routes on startup. :)